# Epilog out of the plot range

Tags: plotting

I need to put some letters besides the plot, i.e. out of the plot range. I thought of using Epilog:

```
ListDensityPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}},
Frame -> False,
Epilog -> {Inset[Style["A", Red, 20], Offset[{0, 0}, Scaled[{0, 0}]]],
Inset[Style["B", Red, 20], Offset[{0, 0}, Scaled[{0.5, 0}]]],
Inset[Style["C", Red, 20], Offset[{0, 0}, Scaled[{1, 0}]]]}]
```

But it does not quite work because there is a limited amount of space besides the plot where I can write, which is not sufficient.

Any ideas?

Comment: `ImagePadding -> 20, PlotRangeClipping -> False`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ListDensityPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 4}}
, Frame -> False
, Epilog -> {
Inset[Style["A", Red, 10], Offset[{-5, -5}, Scaled[{0, 0}]]]
, Inset[Style["B", Red, 20], Offset[{0, -10}, Scaled[{0.5, 0}]]]
, Inset[Style["C", Red, 33], Offset[{0, -15}, Scaled[{1, 0}]]]}
, ImagePadding -> 35
, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]